# R how to take top values by group until its sum exceeds a value

Tags: r, sum, dataframe, cumsum

i have a data frame like this

```
set.seed(500)
df=data.frame(group=c(rep("A",20),rep("B",20),rep("C",20),rep("D",20)),value=round(runif(80,min=1,max=100)))
```

for each group i want to take the top value rows until their sum exceed/meet the target value

```
target=data.frame(group=c("A","B","C","D"),value=c(1000,400,500,300))
```

and output the new groups as 4 data frames.

I sorted them from biggest to smallest

```
df=df[with(df, order(group,-value)), ]
```

the desired output is

```
group value
a    98
a    93
...
a  (sum from 98 to here, the group a subtotal should exceed 1000)
b  93
...
c   99
```

What's the best way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: So can you give the desired output for your sample data? I'm really confused on what the result should be.

Comment: Suppose if the group `a` subtotal for a row say 11 becomes 1000.  and the next row is 0, So, again 1000, for the next row 15.  So, are you saying that you want rows up to 13?

Comment: @santoku  I updated the code.  I hope this works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do: (Using the ordered `df`)

```
 indx <- rep(target$value, table(df$group))
 val1 <- with(df, ave(value, group, FUN=cumsum))
 df[val1 <=indx,]
 #       group value
 #3      A    98
 #8      A    93
 #12     A    89
 #1      A    84
 #9      A    83
 #5      A    81
 #13     A    77
 #2      A    73
 #15     A    73
 #10     A    71
 #18     A    62
 #19     A    61
 #7      A    52
 #39     B    93
 #28     B    90
 #36     B    84
 #37     B    83
 #52     C    99
 #59     C    96
 #45     C    86
 #43     C    84
 #58     C    81
 #65     D    93
 #75     D    87
 #63     D    85
```

Or using `data.table` on the ordered `df`

```
 library(data.table)
 setkey(setDT(df), group)
 setkey(setDT(target), group)
 DT1 <- df[df[target, value1:= i.value][,
           cumsum(value) <value1, by=group]$V1, 1:2, with=FALSE]
```

#### Update

I guess you wanted something like this:

```
  indx2 <- which(val1 <=indx)
  indx3 <- unname(tapply(indx2,cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(indx2)!=1)), tail,1)+1)
  df1 <- df[sort(c(indx2,indx3)),]
   tapply(df1$value, df1$group, FUN=sum)
   # A    B    C    D 
  #1048  432  518  342
```

Comment: thanks. i wanted to use the first method, however, it doesn't return the rows of which the sum exceeds the value, but rather, below it.

Answer (score 1):

This splits and limits the items in the dataframe.  The next one-liner will pick the last row:

```
> lapply( split(df, df[[1]] ) , function(d) d[ cumsum( d[[2]]) < 200 , ] )
$A
  group value
1     A    84
2     A    73

$B
   group value
21     B     9
22     B    81
23     B     5
24     B    54
25     B    28

$C
   group value
41     C    20
42     C    43
43     C    84
44     C    49

$D
   group value
61     D     4
62     D    77
63     D    85
```

Then use `tail`

```
> lapply( split(df, df[[1]] ) , function(d) tail( d[ cumsum( d[[2]]) < 200 , ] ,1))
$A
  group value
2     A    73

$B
   group value
25     B    28

$C
   group value
44     C    49

$D
   group value
63     D    85
```

And if you want to pick the "largest values" then order the dataframe before doing the summation:

```
> lapply( split(df[order(df[[2]], decreasing=TRUE), ] , df[[1]] ) , function(d) tail( d[ cumsum( d[[2]]) < 200 , ] ,1))
$A
  group value
3     A    98

$B
   group value
62     D    77

$C
   group value
71     D    34

$D
   group value
74     D     2
```

Answer (score -1):

If i understand correctly, you want to the the largest values from each group until the sum of all thsoe values exceeds a certain threshold. If so, I think this code will do that

```
newdfs<-Map(function(d, m) { 
    d <-d[order(-d$value), ]
    d[cumsum(d$value) < m, ]
}, split(df, df$group), target$value[match(levels(df$group), target$group)])
newdfs
```

This reurns the data.frames in a list which is almost certainyl better than creating a bunch of new data.frames. If you wanted to merge the results into a single data.frame, you could do

```
do.call(rbind, newdfs)
```

to get

```
     group value
A.3      A    98
A.8      A    93
A.12     A    89
A.1      A    84
A.9      A    83
A.5      A    81
A.13     A    77
A.2      A    73
A.15     A    73
A.10     A    71
A.18     A    62
A.19     A    61
A.7      A    52
B.39     B    93
B.28     B    90
B.36     B    84
B.37     B    83
C.52     C    99
C.59     C    96
C.45     C    86
C.43     C    84
C.58     C    81
D.65     D    93
D.75     D    87
D.63     D    85
```